# Как настроить HTTPS в Spring

Tags: java, spring, https

есть готовое приложение на Spring. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы все запросы к серверу передавались через HTTPS. Потратив несколько часов на гугление, сделал вот что. 
 1. Создал файл contactmanager.keystore вызвав команду в терминале (CMD)

```
keytool -genkey -alias ContactManager -keyalg RSA -keystore c:/contactmanager.keystore
```

2. В файле C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_MyTomcat9\conf\server.xml добавил следующее:
   св

   < Connector port="8443" 
       SSLEnabled="true" 
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       keystoreFile="c:\contactmanager.keystore"
       keystorePass="transmitter"
       sslProtocol="TLS"/>
3. В файле security-config.xml (в самом проекте) написано так:

   ```
   <!--<intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />-->
   <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/console/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/welcome**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/constructions**/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/campaigns**/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/dictionaries**/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/contracts**/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/reservations**/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/payments**/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/reports**/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/users**/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/roles**/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
   ```

Запускаю томкат, все деплоится, запускается. Но для меня остается загадкой, почему нету значка "Зеленый замочек" рядом слева от адресной строки? Такой, как например, на этой странице. И потом, говорят, что этот протокол шифрует все данные и подсмотреть их нельзя. Но как так получается, что все get/post запросы я вижу в их "голом" виде???[image: Параметры отображаются в открытом виде]

Я новичок в HTTPS, многого не знаю. Вроде делал все по туториалам, но эффект не такой какой я ожидал.

Answer (score 4):

> эффект не такой какой я ожидал

Эффект именно такой, какой и должен быть. Ваше спринг-приложение и сервлет-контейнер теперь работают с https, с чем Вас можно поздравить.

> почему нету значка "Зеленый замочек"

Этот значок означает, что сервер является именно тем, за кого себя выдаёт. Для этого сервер должен использовать сертификат, выданный удостоверяющим центром. У вас же сертификат самоподписанный (Вы его сами сгенерировали), и доверия к нему у браузера нет. Кроме того, сервер у вас работает на localhost, и удостоверять соответствие сертификата доменному имени тут смысла нет. Поэтому нет и замочка.

> как так получается, что все get/post запросы я вижу в их "голом" виде

Вы смотрите на на них через консоль разработчика в браузере. Браузер всё расшифровывает специально для вас. Попробуйте запустить перехватчик пакетов, посмотреть, что передается в реальности, и убедитесь, что ваши данные надежно зашифрованы.